# No wifi adapter found Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS bcm4352/14e4:43b1

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, broadcom

Solved and my brain melted

Chili555 you are my hero

the popup secure boot warning I thought getting passed that disabled secure boot

```
sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

disabled secure boot and when the computer booted up it worked normally and I could connect to wifi like nothing was wrong

========================================================================
all I had done before I disabled secure boot. no clue if it made any difference:

I have an ROG G750JW and am completely new to Ubuntu.

I have followed numerous threads with no luck

I ran:`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

with no luck

and I followed:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

any help would be appreciated!

```
$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:dd400000-dd407fff memory:dd200000-dd3fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 74:d0:2b:1a:c8:c5
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.197 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:dd500000-dd53ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2123]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
```

output of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller [8086:0c01] (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI [8086:8c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:8c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 [8086:8c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:8c14] (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:8c16] (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:8c18] (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 [8086:8c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller [8086:8c4b] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:8c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:8c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] [10de:11e2] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0b] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
```

after running:`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

I get back

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for zainen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdrm2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfprint-2-tod1 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglvnd0:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxdamage1:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,068 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731) focal/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5
Get:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731) focal/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5 [1,544 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 187968 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-51-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-51-generic
Done.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod........

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-51-generic
```

I also put in `sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list` to get past the cdrom request

Trying to work with ndiswrapper I cant seem to get the windows driver to work

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmwl63.inf
couldn't open bcmwl63.inf: No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/ndiswrapper line 162.
```

Comment: Did you install bcmwl-kernel-source? Did you disable Secure Boot? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have removed and installed bcmwl-kernel-source a few times with no luck. And I am pretty sure I disabled Secure boot  at some point while going through the threads. I had it show up and it stopped showing up.
Thank you thank you :)

Comment: Could be just the firmware and unfortunately the popular gitub https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm has almost everything except the BCM4352. You could try this mostly harmless firware update method https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/ and finally investiagate this one https://gist.github.com/jppommet/52fe2041e23772a442cf as it has worked for at least one user.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/update-firmware-ubuntu/ method unfortunately didn't work. I tried https://gist.github.com/jppommet/52fe2041e23772a442cf but I have not been able to get ndiswrapper to work or dont understand how to use it.

Comment: ndiswrapper is dead technology. I haven't seen it work properly in many years. Please re-check Secure Boot. This is probably rejected because of Secure Boot: "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Operation not permitted."

Comment: thank you everyone that helped! I have successfully connected to wifi. no more ethernet needed

Comment: Since bcmwl-kernel-source and Secure Boot are mentioned in the usual answer for Broadcom devices and that was evidently the issue, I am voting to close as a duplicate. I'm very glad it's working!