# Broadcom wifi 14e4:4464 adaptor not found

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I was able to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a 2018 MacMini using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127375/install-ubuntu-18-04-on-mac-mini-2018) post. The main remaining issue is that Ubuntu cannot find the wifi adapter. The pci.id (see below) is different from any of the ones listed in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) post where it was suggested to create a new post on askubuntu.com for any unlisted pci.id. Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:07bf]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

is the most in depth

[No wifi adapter found Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS bcm4352/14e4:43b1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284163/no-wifi-adapter-found-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-bcm4352-14e443b1)

is the thread i made when i fixed my problem.

disable secure boot

and install/update your bcmwl-kernel-source

chili555s comments worked for me

Comment: Thanks. The post you linked is the same one that lead me to create this new post actually. The issue is that the pci.id (14e4:4464) is different from any of the ones listed there. I tries all the suggestions that I could find and was not able to eve get the wifi adapter to be recognized by Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: have you disabled secure boot? that was my problem. if you can make your way though mine i apologize its not as coherent mine worked out and mine didnt work for the first link either